# Testing Android Components With Espresso

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-espresso

I have a number of custom Android components and wish to test them using Espresso.  As an Espresso test runs against an `Activity` I added a simple `Activity` class to the `androidTest` directory which programatically creates a view with my component in it ready for testing.

For example if I'm testing a `MyView` component then my Espresso test class might look something like this:

```
public class MyViewTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyViewTestActivity>
{
  private MyViewTestActivity activity;

  public MyViewTest()
  {
    super(MyViewTestActivity.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    // Launches the activity
    activity = getActivity();
  }

  // Ensure that expected items are present
  public void testLayout()
  {
    onView(withId(activity.view.getId())).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  }
}
```

with a simple `MyViewTestActivity` as follows:

```
public class MyViewTestActivity extends Activity
{
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  public LinearLayout layout;
  public MyView view;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    view = new MyView(this);
    view.setId(RANDOM.nextInt());
    view.setItem("Test text");

    layout.addView(view);
    setContentView(layout);
  }
}
```

My problem is I appear to need to add the test `Activity` class, in this case `MyViewTestActivity`, to the main `AndroidManifest.xml` to make this work, otherwise I receive an `Unable to resolve activity for: Intent...` error when attempting to run the test.  However I now have test activities in the main manifest, which seems like a bad thing to do.

How can I set up test-specific activities which are included in the test manifest but not the main one?

I'm using the gradle-based build system for Android.

Comment: It sounds like you want to test a specific component of an activity in your project. If that's the case, then why not run the test against the activity in your main project that uses MyView?

Comment: The component is reusable and shows up in multiple places, so there is no single Activity I could relate it to.  It also feels wrong to do it this way; if I removed the component for the particular activity I had selected for testing then the entire component would no longer have any testing without me refactoring all the tests to use a different activity.  I'd hope that the tests for the view could be separated out in the way that I have outlined above.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to make the View object public?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add `MyViewTestActivity` to the main AndroidManifest.xml.

If you look at the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` source code, you will see that `getActivity()` looks for the tested Activity in the target (i.e., the app under test) context.

Here is the relevant part of the source code.

```
@Override
public T getActivity() {
    // ...
    final String targetPackage = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName();
    // ...
    a = launchActivity(targetPackage, mActivityClass, null);
    // ...
    setActivity(a);
    // ...
}
```

What I do in my projects is that I create a generic TestingActivity, put it in a `.test` package in the target app, and use it for all GUI-component testing. It is not ideal, but I never had any problem with this approach.